# Flying into Canada with an expired passport and a Green Card

Tags: air-travel, canada, alaska-airlines

I have a flight booked for Saturday that my parent booked for me, insisting that I will be able to get into Canada. I have my expired Canadian passport, and my original birth certificate, also I have my permanent resident card issued by America. I am wondering if I will even be allowed on a flight, Alaska Airlines, with an expired passport. I was told that I am Canadian so they can't not let me in, I'm just unsure if they will even let me on a flight, this would be a lot easier and hassle free if I was driving across the border but that is not the case.

Comment: Where are you flying from? That effects what ID and documentation will be acceptable. What is your citizenship?

(But yes broadly, you're right. Canada immigration is unlikley to turn you away, but the airline may not let you board)

Comment: This is more of a question on Alaska's boarding requirements. As a Canadian, they can't turn you around at the border, but can hold you for a period of time until they verify your identity (if you know your SIN, this will be helpful)."At Alaska Airlines, we require each traveler over 18 years old to present valid government issued ID and show it to a Customer Service Agent and at the Security Checkpoint. Children under the age of 18 don’t need photo ID when they are traveling domestically." Looks like the airline requires an in-date travel document, which could be a driver's licence.

Comment: @Richard a driver's license is an ID, but unless it is an "enhanced" license, it is not a travel document.  I read a story about a recently-naturalized family trying to fly from Florida to Canada with proof of citizenship but with passports only from their other country.  They were denied boarding and had to fly to Syracuse and drive to the border.  See http://www.thestar.com/news/immigration/2014/08/04/dual_citizens_carrying_foreign_passport_turned_away_at_florida_airport.html.

Answer (score 1):

TIMATIC thinks your Canadian passport cannot admit you because it's expired. "Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to nationals of Canada must be valid on arrival." Whether you would actually be turned away is another matter, but a cautious airline would be unwise to board you in violation of the clear instruction there.

However, TIMATIC goes on to say under the 'Passport exemptions' category, that you should be admitted with your Green Card: "Permanent residents of USA holding Permanent Resident/Resident Alien Card (Form I-551), arriving from USA or St. Pierre and Miquelon."

Therefore in my view you are in principle entitled to travel and enter Canada merely with your Green Card (although certainly bring along the Canadian passport as well). If you face trouble, ask for the agent in question to confirm the information in TIMATIC, under the passport exemptions category.

```
Information as of  10JUL15 / 1416 UTC
National Canada (CA)            /Residence USA (US)
Embarkation USA (US)            /Destination Canada (CA)
Canada (CA)

Passport required.
- Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
nationals of Canada must be valid on arrival.
- Warning: if departing from the USA (regardless of any
destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/or
is required by the
US immigration authorities.
Passport Exemptions:
- Holders of a valid on arrival NEXUS Card issued to nationals
of Canada, if residing in USA.
- Permanent residents of USA holding Permanent
Resident/Resident Alien Card (Form I-551), arriving from USA
or St. Pierre and Miquelon.

VISA NOT REQUIRED.

Minors:
- If a travel document issued by Canada to minors under 16
years of age displays "Signature Not Required/non requise"

- Parent(s) traveling with a child under 18 years are strongly
Canada (CA)

Vaccinations not required.

Warning:
- Any visitor irrespective of length of intended stay in
Canada may be referred for medical examination if deemed
necessary.
```

Comment: I once got into a little tussle trying to fly US to Canada with fewer than six months remaining on my passport. Canada only requires it be valid upon arrival, but many countries require six months. I needed to make this trip and then I could renew my passport. The agent finally let me on, but she spent a lot of time reading rules on her computer screen. Now I also have Nexus.